# Proving that for all natural number $n$, $n\notin n$

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm having some trouble proving that, for all $n\in \omega$ we have that $n\notin n$. I tried the following:

Let $S=\{n\in \omega:n \notin n \}$. Obviously $0\in S$, But now I'm having trouble with the induction step. is induction the right way to do this?

---

Just so we are all on the same page, these are the definitions that we are using in my Set theory class.

- Let $k$ be a set, then we define the successor of $k$ as: $k^+ = k\cup \{k\}$
- We define the number $0$ as the empty set
- Let $X$ be a set. We say that $X$ is inductive if $0\in X \wedge \forall x(x\in X\implies x^+\in X)$
- AXIOM: There exists an inductive set
- Let $I$ be any inductive set, then we define the set of natural numbers $\omega$ as the intersection of all inductive subsets of $I$. $\omega$ is the smallest inductive set

Comment: Can you please add the definition of the natural numbers, to make sure we're on the same page? Thanks!

Comment: In ZFC no set is an element of itself. This follows from the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_set_is_an_element_of_itself).

Comment: Given @JairTaylor's point, you should probably specify e.g. $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ (`\mathsf{ZF}^-`) as your set theory. Hint: if $\omega\setminus S$ has minimal element $k$ each $j\in k$ satisfies $j\notin j$, so...

Comment: @Matija Just wrote the definitions as you asked

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1896329/1096797) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that no natural number can be subset of any of its elements.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896108/proof-that-no-natural-number-can-be-subset-of-any-of-its-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed as follows (modified from the original due to your comment).

Base Case: The proposition is true for $n = 0$.

Proof: By definition, $0 = \{\}$. Now $\{\} \notin \{\}$, since by definition, the set $\{\}$ is defined by the property that it has no elements. Therefore, $0 \notin \{\}$.

Additional base case: $n^{+} \notin n$ for $n = 0$.

Proof: Similarly, by definition, $0 = \{\}$ and $0^{+} = \{\} \cup \{\{\}\}$. Now $\{\} \cup \{\{\}\} \notin \{\}$, since by definition, the set $\{\}$ is defined by the property that it has no elements. Therefore, $0^{+} \notin \{\}$.

Inductive Step (using your notation): if $n \notin n$ and $n^{+} \notin n$, then $n^{+} \notin n^{+}$.

Proof: Suppose $n^{+} \in n^{+}$. Then, by definition, $n \cup \{n\} \in n \cup \{n\}$. This means either $n \cup \{n\} \in n$ or $n \cup \{n\} \in \{n\}$. If the first is true, it violates the second inductive assumption. If the second is true, it means $n \cup \{n\} = n$, since $n$ is the only element of $\{n\}$. But if $n \cup \{n\} = n$, any element of $n \cup \{n\}$ is also in $n$ by the definition of set equality. In particular, $n \in n \cup \{n\}$, so this implies $n \in n$, violating the first inductive assumption. This proves the result by contradiction.

I think this is what you were trying to ask.

Comment: You can use the fact that $n$ is transitive to prove that $n \cup \{n\} \in n \implies n \in n$, but how do you prove that $n \cup \{n\} \in \{n\} \implies \{n\} \in \{n\}$?

Comment: I updated the proof. Let me know what you think.

Comment: “any element of $n \cup \{n\}$ is also an element of $n$ by the definition of set equality” Actually, it is by the substitution property of equality. Equality is a primitive notion and is not “defined”.

Comment: 'Equality is a primitive notion and is not “defined”.' I am more of a physical applications and engineering type, but my recollection from doing set theory stuff in college is that strictly speaking $A \subset B$ is defined as $\{x | x \in A \implies x \in B\}$, and $A = B$ is defined as $A \subset B \land B \subset A$. I guess the more primitive element equality is not "defined" so to speak. So I did mean that sentence the way I wrote it. I'm not sure if other definitions are used elsewhere.